# harvest chosen plugin fails to show validation messages for asp.net mvc dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I am unable to get validation messages after changing my dropdownlist to chosen dropdown list. Chosen plugin can be found [here](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/chosen/)

```
Jquery code
    $('#SelectedPropertyGroup').chosen();    

UI Code
    <div>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedGroup, Model.Groups, "Select Group", new
                    {
                        @onchange = "javascript:ValidateApplicationSelection(this, 'Group');",
                        @placeholder = "Please select a product"
                    })
                </div>

                <div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedGroup, "", new { id = "valGroup" })
                </div>


Model Code

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Group")]
            [DisplayName("Group: ")]
            public string SelectedGroup { get; set; }
```

Comment: Chosen doesn't have anything to do with this. Worse case scenario, it might not pass a value to the original select element, but that would *cause* an error, not suppress the display of one. Check the rest of your code. In particular, you're actually setting the validation message to "a", if there's an error, so maybe you're just missing the `a` on your page.

Comment: sorry for the typo. I dont have 'a' there its blank.

Comment: well, there you go. That second parameter overrides the default error message. You've essentially told it to always print a blank string when there's an error.

Answer (score 3):

The client side validation ignores hidden fields by default -- Chosen hides the "real" select element when it applies it's magic.  You can change the validator defaults like so:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" });
```

This will set the validator to ignore any hidden fields that aren't select elements.

The [default for the ignore](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) is `":hidden"`

Comment: How to define validator in this code? Should I try this code on document.ready?

Comment: This should be defined after you've loaded the jQuery unobtrusive validation bundle.  It's automatically included in ASP.MVC scaffoled edit/create views.  The bundle is ~/bundles/jqueryval.

Comment: Sorry for one more question. I am unable to locate file you told me. Could you please elaborate file location please.